# Getting Gmail in Emacs?

Tags: email, gmail, emacs

I'm trying to learn Emacs, and I think that getting gmail right in it would be cool. I've tried a but of tutorials online, but I couldn't figure out what a lot of them were talking about. A lot of them listed elisp code but didn't tell where to put it, and others just didn't work (they created errors). All I really want is to send and receive email - folders and smtp(?) are completely optional.

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

**Edit:** I found http://www.gohome.org/wl/doc/wl_toc.html to be helpful in figuring out Wanderlust.

Comment: Why do people insist so much on doing other things than editing text, with Emacs? This has always amazed me ;)

Comment: Emacs- not just an editor, an operating system!

Comment: This is built in: C-q C-p C-x fgh 2 99z {Return} :P

Comment: @Gnoupi - I think they don't even know themselves. They just like the hype.

Comment: Emacs Gnus is an outstanding email client.

Comment: @Gnoupi.  Emacs is a software development platform that promotes plain text/keyboard user interfaces (sometimes called "text user interfaces").  It contrasts with Java and .NET that promote graphical user interfaces.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Emacs is *really* great for browsing and editing text; what is email except a special case of this?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis - Organizing, sorting, filtering, archiving. The base of email is reading and writing text, for sure. But when it gets busy, you can need more than just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success using wanderlust.  This is a good tutorial for setting it up:

http://box.matto.nl/emacsgmail.html

Answer (score 11):

I have it setup as a gnus secondary source.  In `.gnus.el` I have:

```
(add-to-list 'gnus-secondary-select-methods
  '(nnimap "gmail"
    (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
    (nnimap-server-port 993)
    (nnimap-stream ssl)
    (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo.gpg")
    ))
```

and in `.authinfo.gpg` I have:

```
machine "gmail" imap.gmail.com login username@gmail.com password trustno1
```

You'll need to enable imap on your accounts to make it work.  `.authinfo.gpg` is gpg encrypted (for password privacy) and I have the `easypg` package installed to decrypt it on demand.

I send email locally, so you'll have to look at [emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail) to work out how to send it via gmail's servers.

Comment: Checkout Nathaniel's posts on GMail with Emacs at http://nflath.com/2009/10/gmail-from-emacs/ and http://nflath.com/2009/10/more-gmail-with-emacs/