# Cross platform, gmail compatible email client for Emacs

Tags: email, emacs

I spend alot of my time in Emacs, and move between Windows, Linux, and Mac OS at least once a day since these are the machines my company has available to use. I spend alot of time in gmail using gmail folders too, and would like to find a cross platform email client for emacs which can support gmail too.

Note: I would like to find a client which is "stable", and has good support and documentation.

Comment: See also the answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/69504/getting-gmail-in-emacs).

Answer (score 4):

A long time ago, I used to read my e-mail in gnus.  A quick search shows that gnus supports IMAP, and since GMail supports IMAP, it should (in theory) work.  Here's the some documentation on how to setup imap in gnus: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/IMAP.html.

I will also add that I have not tried IMAP in gnus myself, so YMMV.

Comment: Do you know if there are any easier to follow guides on setting up GNUS mail, as the link provided seems to require alot of prior knowledge

Comment: You might want to try one of these pages (I plan to myself): http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail , http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6449

Comment: I tried the first link (emacswiki) and was able to get things running in about 5 minutes.  The one caveat I found is trying to view HTML email.  It looks like HTML, not like text.

Answer (score 2):

Over a very long number of years, I have used Rmail, VM (old and new), Gnus and a few others.
None of them have "stuck" or qualify as stable and work with IMAP (Rmail is the best choice but does not truly support IMAP).  So when I started embracing Google, I was very frustrated with the mail situation not initially caring for the Gmail web client.  After a while however I started to really, really like the Gmail web client and when I found [a Google Chrome extension that used Emacs](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh) (via Emacs server) I was a happy camper.  This is my current Email/Emacs model and I am quite happy with it, fwiw.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can download this and try it?

Comment: Edit with Emacs: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh

Answer (score 2):

I have used at least Rmail, VM, gnus, mew, and wanderlust in emacs for email in the past. Gnus I liked the least for email. Mew and wanderlust are amazing! For some years now I email with wanderlust and it is fast and supports IMAP very well.